# How to join a table with specific conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select data from a table like this (the table name is `conversations_users`) :

[image: Table content sample]

I would like to be able to retrieve a conversation ID that includes only two users. As instance, if I search a conversation specific to users 1 and 3 the conversation number 6 should be the unique result, because the conversation 5 also includes user 2.

I have tried to perform a request like

```
SELECT * FROM conversations_users AS table1 JOIN 
              conversations_users AS table2 ON
              table1.conversation_ID = table2.conversationID
        WHERE table1.userID = 3 AND
              table2.userID = 1
```

But it returns both conversations 5 and 6. How can I fix that ?

Thank you in advance,

Pierre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM conversations_users AS table1 JOIN 
              conversations_users AS table2 
                ON table1.conversation_ID = table2.conversation_ID
        WHERE table1.userID = 3 AND
              table2.userID = 1
```

**Update**:
To get only coversations, where only 1 and 3 are involved, you can use having clause:

```
SELECT table1.conversation_ID FROM conversations_users AS table1 JOIN 
              conversations_users AS table2 
                ON table1.conversation_ID = table2.conversation_ID
        WHERE table1.userID = 3 AND
              table2.userID = 1
        Group by table1.conversation_ID 
        having Count(*) = 2
```

Comment: It is still returning me the conversations 5 and 6.. How could I prevent that ?

Comment: @axiac But it wasn't as i answered the question. OP has changed it later

Comment: @PierreHUBERT Do not use the old style implezite join Syntax. Use the newer explizit style

Answer (score 0):

The query you need looks like:

```
SELECT conversation_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userID ORDER BY userID) as users
FROM conversations_users
GROUP BY conversation_ID
HAVING users = '1,3'
```

The `GROUP BY` clause groups the rows having the same `conversation_ID` and from each group it generates a new record that contains the `conversation_ID` and the distinct values of `userID`, in ascending order, concatenated with comma (`,`).

The `HAVING` clause keeps only those records that have `'1,3'` in the column `users` computed by the `GROUP BY` clause.

The query produces the output you need but it is not efficient because it reads the entire table. It could be more efficient by picking first the conversations of users `1` and `3` and then applying the above only to them.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT conversation_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT userID ORDER BY userID) as users
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM conversations_users
    WHERE userID in (1, 3)
) conversations
GROUP BY conversation_ID
HAVING users = '1,3'
```

In order to work faster than the previous query, the `conversations_users` must have an index on the `userID` column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict to those conversations which involve exactly n number of users. I think below generic query should work. Replacing 'n' as per requirement.

```
select * 
from  conversations_users
where conversation_id IN (select conversation_id
                      from conversations_users
                      group by conversation_id
                      having count(userid) = 2)
```

Thanks,
Amitabh

Answer (score 0):

The inner select grabs all conversationIDs with other users than 1 or 3

the outer select (with distinct) collects all conversations wich are NOT in this subset

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversationID
  FROM conversations_users t1
 WHERE conversationID NOT IN ( SELECT conversationID
                                 FROM conversations_users
                                WHERE userID NOT in (1, 3)
                             )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join with where condition in this case.

```
SELECT #, userid ,conversation_ID FROM user AS table1 JOIN 
              conversations_users AS table2 
                ON user_ID = conversation_ID
        WHERE table1.userID = 3 AND
              table2.userID = 1
        Group by conversation_ID
```

You can apply suitable condition by where clause instead of group by